# VPS Nginx/ Apache | multi website doesn't work

Tags: apache, nginx

I've moved 2 domains on the VPS and they work fine, just **one at a time**.

If I disable one, then the other one works - not both.

dom1.com , dom2.com

have the same DNS records, except the A records with their domain-name pointing to the same IP on the VPS, their DNS records are both on CloudFlare, and they're both configured the same way on the VPS (with aaPanel).
The only difference is their site directory.

Do you know what could trigger this issue?

- CentOS 8
- aaPanel 6.8.21
- Apache 2.4 (same issue on Nginx 1.19)
- DNS manager: CloudFlare

Many Thanks

**dom1.com | config**

```
   DocumentRoot "/www/wwwroot/dom1.com"
   ServerName 745e5c8e.dom1.com
   ServerAlias dom1.com mail.dom1.com
   #errorDocument 404 /404.html
   ErrorLog "/www/wwwlogs/dom1.com-error_log"
   CustomLog "/www/wwwlogs/dom1.com-access_log" combined
   #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_START
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [L,R=301]
   </IfModule>
   #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_END
   #referenced redirect rule, if commented, the configured redirect rule will be invalid
   IncludeOptional /www/server/panel/vhost/apache/redirect/dom1.com/*.conf

   #DENY FILES
    <Files ~ (\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)$>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
   </Files>
   
   #PHP
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
           SetHandler "proxy:unix:/tmp/php-cgi-73.sock|fcgi://localhost"
   </FilesMatch>
   
   #PATH
   <Directory "/www/wwwroot/dom1.com">
       SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
       DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.html default.htm
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
   DocumentRoot "/www/wwwroot/dom1.com/"
   ServerName SSL.dom1.com
   ServerAlias dom1.com mail.dom1.com 
   #errorDocument 404 /404.html
   ErrorLog "/www/wwwlogs/dom1.com-error_log"
   CustomLog "/www/wwwlogs/dom1.com-access_log" combined
   
   #SSL
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/dom1.com/fullchain.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/dom1.com/privkey.pem
   SSLCipherSuite EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5
   SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
   SSLHonorCipherOrder On
   
   
   #PHP
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
           SetHandler "proxy:unix:/tmp/php-cgi-73.sock|fcgi://localhost"
   </FilesMatch>
   

   #DENY FILES
    <Files ~ (\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)$>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
   </Files>

   #PATH
   <Directory "/www/wwwroot/dom1.com/">
       SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
       DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.html default.htm
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**dom2.com | config**

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/wwwroot/dom2.com"
    ServerName 218ac146.dom2.com
    ServerAlias dom2.com mail.dom2.com
    #errorDocument 404 /404.html
    ErrorLog "/www/wwwlogs/dom2.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/www/wwwlogs/dom2.com-access_log" combined

    #DENY FILES
     <Files ~ (\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)$>
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
    </Files>
    
    #PHP
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/tmp/php-cgi-73.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    
    #PATH
    <Directory "/www/wwwroot/dom2.com">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.html default.htm
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
aaPanel added a wrong sub-domain in their config file.
So fixing that resolved the issue.